# Updating a database record every month

Tags: java, mysql, date, calendar

I need to update some user records in my database every month (specifically, give them credits that belong to their subscription), starting the day they sign up. I thought of doing it this way:

Once every day...

- Find all users that have been updated a month ago (or more, in case the process fails for a 
  day)
- Update them
- Increase their last update day by a month

Sounds simple, but simpler than it is. The problem is that months don't always have the same number of days. For example, if somebody signs up march 31, when should he be updated? April 30, may 1? Or should I simply restrict the range of update days to the lowest common range, 28? I could of course just do it on the 1st, for everyone, though that's less ideal.

Do you have experiences to share with situations like this? I'm using MySQL 5 from Java+JPA+Hibernate. If it helps, I'm already using JodaTime for something else.

Comment: Do you want this to be done in JAVA or in MySQL.

Comment: Preferably in Java, since direct access to MySQL is cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the maximum day of the month by following code.

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();     
    java.sql.Date userSignupdate = ...;
    calendar.setTimeInMillis( userSignupdate );

    // maxDay will hold the maximum date of the month. {28,29,30,31}
    int maxDay = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Comment: My solution can be seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844061/calculate-month-difference-in-joda-time I'm using Joda-Time's version of getting the maximum day of the month.

Answer (score 1):

If using spring, [Spring scheduling](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html) is what you can take a look at. You can have a method like this:

```
@Scheduled("0 0 1 * *") // cron expression
public void executeOnceAMonth() {
}
```

and just have `<task:annotation-driven />` (more details on configuration - in the linked document)

This is actually an abstraction over [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/), so you can also use a Quartz job to do it.

Comment: What's happening at 10 am on Feb 28th with this Expression `@Scheduled(cron="0 10 30 * *")`

Comment: That would make the method execute every month, yes, but without any record of it in the database. See my comment on JohnIdol why that's undesirable.

Comment: @powerMicha I copy-pasted the cron expr. from somewhere, not sure if it's correct.

Comment: @Bart van Heukelom that thing must run in a transaction, which will solve all such issues.

Answer (score 0):

Can u just have a scheduled job running the 20th of each month (or whatever) and calculate credits for each user so far?

I would not complicate the situation with offsets and stuff if not strictly necessary.

Comment: That's not reliable enough. The process may crash halfway or not run at all for some reason. When it runs next day, it should pick up correctly without giving people double credits or skipping them a month.

Comment: Well you could always - I don't know - make it reliable? Trust me, *there are ways* :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead have a column 'next_update_time', so when a user signs up the column value should be updated with the time after a month

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
cal.getTime();
```

run a cronjob (invoke another small java code) every few hours to check for columns which have next_update_time >= current time, if yes,update the records and set the next_update_time value to next month.

Comment: That would work. One issue I can see is that if I ever need to change the program so that it updates once a week, for example, it would take a month before every user benefits.

Comment: have a last_updated_time column too, if you need to change frequency then updating the 'next_update_time' column accordingly is a matter of a sql query.

Comment: or can have only last_updated_time and cronjob should take care of when to update next..select * from tab where last_updated_time > timestampadd(days, n ,now()) (or month,1 if needed in months)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why doing it on the first of the month is less ideal. Especially if you give a  partial credit to bring each user up to the same date

The simplest way of handling this in my experience is to "normalise" each user to the first of the month when they join. So if somebody joins on the 15th June they get a

1-(15/30) x monthly_credits credit.

From that point on it is the 1st of the month.

NB you can use a similar method to assign users to different days (1-28) if you want to spread them out for a particular reason.