# Get difference between two dates in months using Java

Tags: java, date

I need to get difference between two dates using Java. I need my result to be in months.

Example:

> Startdate = 2013-04-03 
>            enddate = 2013-05-03 
>            Result should be 1

if the interval is

> Startdate = 2013-04-03 
>            enddate = 2014-04-03 
>            Result should be 12

Using the following code I can get the results in days. How can I get in months?

```
Date startDate = new Date(2013,2,2);
Date endDate = new Date(2013,3,2);
int difInDays = (int) ((endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24));
```

Comment: Can you use external libraries, like JodaTime?

Comment: If you use JodaTime then there is a similar question with a simple answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844061/calculate-month-difference-in-joda-time

Comment: What do you want between 2013-01-31 and 2013-02-01? 0 months or 1 month?

Comment: In this case i dont really want days to calculated.I just want exact month difference

Answer (score 111, accepted):

If you can't use JodaTime, you can do the following:

```
Calendar startCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
startCalendar.setTime(startDate);
Calendar endCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
endCalendar.setTime(endDate);

int diffYear = endCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - startCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int diffMonth = diffYear * 12 + endCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) - startCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Note that if your dates are 2013-01-31 and 2013-02-01, you get a distance of 1 month this way, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: +1 This will work for every year difference. (i.e.) `Startdate = 2014-04-03 enddate = 2013-04-03 Result should be 12` as OP said. **UPDATE** Yes, he will get a 1 month difference even if it is only 1 day difference, but OP specified that he wants it in months. 1 month its not a real difference between these dates, but 0 it's not even more real difference. For that, if you want 0 months you can do something like `Math.floor`, or something like that.

Comment: @Etienne Miret : I am getting following error. The method startCalendar(int) is undefined for the type

Comment: @ashu `startCalendar(int)` is not a method. You have an error in your syntax, maybe. You have to do `startCalendar.setTime(int)`. In this case, `int` it's `startDate.getTime()`. So you will need to have in your code this `startCalendar.setTime(startDate.getTime())`

Comment: Ya but write the code exactly what given above but still am getting error like this

Comment: Sorry i did a sysntax mistake there

Comment: Now i got the result .Thank you

Comment: @ashu Indeed, I made a typo in my answer, which is now corrected.

Comment: @DaGLiMiOuX the [Calendar.setTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTime(java.util.Date)) method takes a `Date` argument, not an `int`.

Comment: @EtienneMiret I meant `long` not `int`. My bad :)

Comment: There is one issue on this code not mentioned and that being if the startDate is after the endDate. Then it will not be correct. Or you get negative numbers.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Joda time library for Java. It would be much easier to calculate time-diff between dates with it.

Sample snippet for time-diff:

```
Days d = Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate);
int days = d.getDays();
```

Comment: FYI, the Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode, with its team advising migration to the java.time classes.

Answer (score -6):

You can try this:

```
Calendar sDate = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar eDate = Calendar.getInstance();
sDate.setTime(startDate.getTime());
eDate.setTime(endDate.getTime());
int difInMonths = sDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) - eDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

I think this should work. I used something similar for my project and it worked for what I needed (year diff). You get a `Calendar` from a `Date` and just get the month's diff.

Comment: Won't work if the two dates belong to different years.

Comment: @EtienneMiret That's true. This will work only for dates in the same year.

Comment: I'd suggest to delete this answer because it's not implemented properly and currently is obsolete.

Comment: @AlexRudenko If you are going to complain about a 7 years old answer, you have a serious problem. Lol.

Comment: Whether I have a problem or not does not improve this answer which is not quite the same as cask-matured brandy and therefore it has not got better for these 7 years :)