# how to calculate age or difference between two dates in java

Tags: java, date, date-difference

I want to get the number of months between 2 dates.The dates are someones birthday and the current date.So i m getting the number of years in between the two dates but not the number of months..

Suppose my dates are **06/09/2011** and **06/11/2012**.So i want the answer to be 1yr 2mths .I am getting the year but not the month.Please help.Below is the code for getting the number of years

```
 public int getAge(Date dateOfBirth)      {                                                                                                                                                                         

    today = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    Calendar birthDate = Calendar.getInstance();

    birthDate.setTime(dateOfBirth);
    if (birthDate.after(today)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't be born in the future");
    }

    age = today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - birthDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = today.get(Calendar.MONTH) - birthDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);

    if ( (birthDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) - today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) > 3) ||
            (birthDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) > today.get(Calendar.MONTH ))){
        days = birthDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        age--;

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "inside if", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("month is",month+"");
        Log.e("Days",days+ " left");


    }else if ((birthDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) == today.get(Calendar.MONTH )) &&
              (birthDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) > today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH ))){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "inside else if", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        age--;
    }

    return age;
```

Comment: Check out my answer and try out.

Comment: Try searching before posting. Answered many times on StackOverflow.com. Focus on Joda-Time which includes classes for exactly your purpose. Start by reading the question, [Joda-Time: what's the difference between Period, Interval and Duration?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2653567/642706).

Comment: I am not using joda time so i was looking for an alternative

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have recently created a demo and uploaded [here](https://bitbucket.org/joisar/d_datediffandagecalc).

It is using [`JodaTime`](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time) library for efficient results.

I hope it will be useful.

**Screenshot:**

[image: screenshot]

**Code:**

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private SimpleDateFormat mSimpleDateFormat;
    private PeriodFormatter mPeriodFormat;

    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
    private Date birthDate;


    private TextView tvStartDate,tvEndDate,tvDifferenceStandard,tvDifferenceCustom,tvBirthDate,tvAgeStandard,tvAgeCustom;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();

        //determine dateDiff
        Period dateDiff = calcDiff(startDate,endDate);
        tvDifferenceStandard.setText(PeriodFormat.wordBased().print(dateDiff));
        tvDifferenceCustom.setText( mPeriodFormat.print(dateDiff));


        //determine age
        Period age = calcDiff(birthDate,new Date());
        tvAgeStandard.setText(PeriodFormat.wordBased().print(age));
        tvAgeCustom.setText( mPeriodFormat.print(age));

    }

    private void init() {

        //ui
        tvStartDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvStartDate);
        tvEndDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvEndDate);
        tvDifferenceStandard = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDifferenceStandard);
        tvDifferenceCustom = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDifferenceCustom);
        tvBirthDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvBirthDate);
        tvAgeStandard = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvAgeStandard);
        tvAgeCustom = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvAgeCustom);



        //components
        mSimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
        mPeriodFormat = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().appendYears().appendSuffix(" year(s) ").appendMonths().appendSuffix(" month(s) ").appendDays().appendSuffix(" day(s) ").printZeroNever().toFormatter();


        try {
            startDate = mSimpleDateFormat.parse(tvStartDate.getText().toString());
            endDate =  mSimpleDateFormat.parse(tvEndDate.getText().toString());
            birthDate = mSimpleDateFormat.parse(tvBirthDate.getText().toString());

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Period calcDiff(Date startDate,Date endDate)
    {
        DateTime START_DT = (startDate==null)?null:new DateTime(startDate);
        DateTime END_DT = (endDate==null)?null:new DateTime(endDate);

        Period period = new Period(START_DT, END_DT);

        return period;

    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<TextView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Date Diff Calculator"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Start Date:" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvStartDate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="06/09/2011" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="End Date:" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvEndDate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="29/10/2013" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Difference (Standard)" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDifferenceStandard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="result" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Difference (Custom)" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDifferenceCustom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="result" />


<TextView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Age Calculator"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Birth Date:" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvBirthDate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="01/09/1989" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Age (Standard)" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvAgeStandard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="result" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Age (Custom)" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvAgeCustom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="result" />
```

**Note:**

1)
don't forget to `add JodaTime library` to your project

2)
As you can see in layout file, I have used fixed value for `"Start Date","End Date" to calculate Date Difference` and fixed value for `"Birth Date" to calculate Age`. You may `replace it with your dynamic values`.

Comment: There is no code example here. I shouldn't have to navigate to another site (one that may be down or blocked by my work) to see your answer.

Comment: Great solution, you just forgot appendWeeks().appendSuffix(" week(s) ")

Comment: @AviParshan Yeah, I did that intentionally to explain custom formatter, weeks parameter is already there in standard format :)

Answer (score 0):

[Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) has code to do all this and more

You can do the following to get the month between two dates:

```
Calendar startCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
startCalendar.setTime(startDate);
Calendar endCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
endCalendar.setTime(endDate);

int diffYear = endCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - startCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int diffMonth = diffYear * 12 + endCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) - startCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Check out [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558898/get-difference-between-two-dates-in-months-using-java)

**Note:** that if your dates are `2013-01-31` and `2013-02-01`, you get a distance of 1 month this way, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: What you are saying is the total time in months but i want the age in months and days like Your Age is 22 yrs 5 mths 23 days

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

Because this answer got referenced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30842691/how-to-calculate-age-using-date-of-birth)…

With [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes you can calculate the age very easy:

```
long years = ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(LocalDate.of(1900, Month.NOVEMBER, 20), LocalDate.now());
```

or (if you need year and months)

```
Period p = Period.between(birthday, today);
p.getYears();
p.getMonths();
```

To count all the months in the entire period, as asked in the Question, call [`toTotalMonths`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#toTotalMonths--).

```
int totalMonths = p.toTotalMonths();
```

Answer (score 0):

Age can be calculate in a very easy way. The following is my complete java code .

```
 public class age {


    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        Date dd=new Date();
        int d=Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("dd").format(dd));
        int m=Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("MM").format(dd));
        int y=Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(dd));
         System.out.println( "Enter Day ");
        int d1=Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
        System.out.println( "Enter Month ");
        int m1=Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
         System.out.println( "Year");
        int y1=Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
        if(d<d1){
            d+=30;
            m-=1;
        }
        if(m<m1){
            m+=12;
            y-=1;
        }
      System.out.println((y-y1)+" years "+(m-m1)+"  month "+(d-d1)+" days ");

    }
 }
```