# How to get dates in month and days

Tags: java, date

Sorry, I tried referred the methods from [Similar Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558898/get-difference-between-two-dates-in-months-using-java). But i still cannot get solution. How can i get the output months and days between two difference dates? Any helps would be appreciated.Thanks.

P/s : JodaTime not applicable.

What i've tried so far.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String start       = "03-01-2015";   
String end         = "01-11-2014";

Date startdate = formatter.parse(start);
Date enddate   = formatter.parse(end);
Calendar startCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
startCalendar.setTime(startdate);
Calendar endCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
endCalendar.setTime(enddate);

int diffYear = endCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - startCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int diffMonth = diffYear * 12 + endCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) -startCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you want.

```
int diffDay= endCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) -startCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

System.err.println("diffMonth==="+diffMonth +" Month(s) and " + diffDay + " Day(s)");
```

Comment: hi Wissam Mhaidly.. i found some error from the code..

if date from 2/8/2016 to 2/2/2017 the sql
result show : 12 month -6days

it supposely show 11month and 25days.. how can i fixed this hm ?

Comment: @user3835327  the dates above '2/8/2016 to 2/2/2017' will give you  6 months,  note the dates format specified in your code above are in "dd-MM-yyyy" format  not "MM-dd-yyyy"

Answer (score 0):

In java8 you can do it like this:

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2004, Month.JANUARY, 1);
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2005, Month.JANUARY, 1);

long monthsInYear2 = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(startDate, endDate);
```

(source: http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/number-of-months-between-two-dates/)