# How to Calculate Accurate Month diff b\w two dates in java

Tags: java, mysql, date

I want diff of month between two dates . Diff of month calculate such as

```
start_date = "2017-08-30";
end_date = "2017-09-01";
```

diff of month is 0

and

```
start_date = "2017-06-05";
end_date = "2017-08-20";
```

diff of month is 2

and
start_date = "2017-08-15";
end_date = "2017-08-15";
diff of month is 1

I am using calender of java for dates handling. After google i can not find accurate solution for that can anyone help me how can i calculate correct month diff between two dates .

Comment: Convert these days in milliseconds and then perform the calculation, restore the format back by `SimpleDateFormat`class

Comment: please let me know more about the condition, any rounding of dates logic or simple calculate the diff of months such as diff 1.5 months?

Comment: Dublicate of [Get difference between two dates in months using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558898/get-difference-between-two-dates-in-months-using-java) and [Java Date month difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086396/java-date-month-difference)

Comment: Pso simple if date1 is 2017-08-30 and  date2 is 2017-09-15 then month should be 0.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using java 8 you can calculate the difference between 2 `Temporal` objects

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2017, 6, 5);
LocalDate end = LocalDate.of(2017, 8, 15);
long delta = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(start, end);

System.out.println(delta);
```

ofcourse you need to create those localDate instances from the SLQ data... but that is not the big problem

using Joda (almost the same as java8 actually):

```
DateTime start = new DateTime().withDate(2017, 6, 5);
DateTime end = new DateTime().withDate(2017, 8, 15);

System.out.println(Months.monthsBetween(start , end).getMonths());
```

for the old broken `java.util.Date` then see the duplicated question