# how to clear sharedpreferance exactly at 12am in broadcast receiver android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, time, broadcastreceiver

I want to clear my shared preferance field phonenumber exactly at 12 am in broadcast receiver. How will I do that ?
Here is my code ...

````
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context .getSharedPreferences("connect", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


        String username = prefs.getString("phonenumber", null ) ;  

    }



}```
````

Comment: Are you asking how to clear the preference or a logic for clearing at 12 am ? To clear the preference `preferences.edit().clear().apply()` to clear single object `preferences.edit().putString(key, "").apply()` for 12 am logic you could try alarm manager or JobScheduler

Comment: @ShahnawazAnsari please help me help me to do this ? how can i use alarmmanager or jobscheduler ?

Answer (score 0):

Alarm Manager

The Alarm Manager holds a CPU wake lock as long as the alarm receiver's onReceive() method is executing.

```
timer = new Timer();

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        synchronized public void run() {

           preferences.edit().putString(key, "").apply()
            }

        }, TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1), TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1));
```

ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.

You can use java.util.Timer or ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor (preferred) to schedule an action to occur at regular intervals on a background thread.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate
      (new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            // call the preferences clear logic 
         }
      }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

EDit:

You can actually save the install time and then do a calculation to see if a week has elapsed. If it has clear the shared preference

```
//First time
long installed = context
    .getPackageManager()
    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackag‌​eName(), 0)
    .firstInstallTime;
```

Ref:[More on periodic event handling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14377875/13533028)
[Get install time and clear shared preference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54043602/13533028)

Comment: how can i change timing to 11 pm to clear preference

Comment: In the code as you can see there are no specific times it work son intervals so would work for any time

Comment: can you write in the code , after 7 day interval , clear sharedpreference ?

Comment: Updated the code in the answer..Please check

Comment: any othere method ?

Comment: does this solution not work?